# What is destructive?

Tags: ruby, arrays, flatten

I know that Ruby has many methods, especially on array or array like objects, for example `sort` or `flatten`. However, these methods also have a twin (the one with an exclamation mark) like `sort!` and `flatten!`.

Now my questions are:

- What is the difference between `flatten` and `flatten!` (destructive flatten)?
- A more general question, why is it called destructive?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) and [`flatten!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten-21)? It's pretty easy to tell by reading the description and looking at the examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is simply that `flatten` returns a copy of the array (a new array that is flattened) and `flatten!` does the modification "in place" or "destructively."  The term destructive means that it modifies the original array.  This is useful for when you know what you want your end result to be and don't mind if the original structure gets changed.

As @padde pointed out, it will consume less memory as well to perform something destructively since the structure could be large and copying will be expensive.

However, if you want to keep your original structure it is best to use the method and make a copy.

Here is an example using `sort` and `sort!`.

```
a = [9, 1, 6, 5, 3]
b = a.sort
c = [7, 6, 3]
c.sort!
```

Contents:

```
a = [9, 1, 6, 5, 3]
b = [1, 3, 5, 6, 9]
c = [3, 6, 7]
```

Comment: As a side note: sometimes mutators are a lot faster than their bangless equivalents. Depending on the underlying algorithm and the amount of data, a lot of copying around can be saved.

Answer (score 1):

> [`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten):- Returns a new array that is a one-dimensional flattening of self (recursively).
>
> [`Array#flatten!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten-21):- Flattens self in place.

```
a = [1,2,[3,4]]
p a.object_id #=> 74502050
p a.flatten.object_id #=> 74501960
p a.flatten!.object_id #=> 74502050
```

`flatten` creates a new array object, as `a.flatten.object_id` shows a different value from `a.object_id`.

`flatten!` modifies the object that `a` references, which `a.flatten!.object_id` shows as `74502050`.