# Why is gsub complaining about nil when my object isn't nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, gsub

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 and have the following to trim all white space from a particular expression …

```
  puts "division: #{division}$$"
  division = division.gsub(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '')
```

when I run this, eventually my program dies with this output …

```
division: 18-29$$
Error during processing: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
/Users/mikeb/Documents/workspace/runtrax/app/models/race_time.rb:27:in `block in <class:RaceTime>'
/Users/mikeb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `instance_exec'
/Users/mikeb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block in make_lambda'
/Users/mikeb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
/Users/mikeb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
/Users/mikeb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `each'
/Users/mikeb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
/Users/mikeb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
…
```

I don’t understand why gsub thinks its getting a nil when the line above, the string is clearly not empty (a value of 18-29 is printed out).  Curiously, I can’t reproduce this in a Rails console, so I’m wondering it here’s something else going on or if there’s a better way to write the above.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error if `division #=> "18-29"`.

Comment: `binding.pry` or `byebug` instead of `puts` and inspect the value.

Comment: Is this the real code or did you leave some thing out between these 2 lines?

Comment: I thinks it's not your code, it is some thing wrong how you use the callback

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. gsub is a method on strings. test out the type for "division" with this: `puts division.class` you may find that while "division" is not "nil," it may not be a string so it's throwing an error. see [HERE](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) for more description.
2. since your code is meant to change the value of division, you can do so more elegantly and economically using a "destructive method" as follows: `division.gsub!(/\A\p{Space}+|\p{Space}+\z/, '')` See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682861/what-is-destructive) for a discussion of destructive methods (note the "!", also called "bang"). This probably doesn't solve the original question, but it does pretty up your code.